# Properly configuration of IIS6 and WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, iis-6

I have windows server 2003 with iss 6 and installed framework NET 4.0. Then  with this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa751792.aspx I configured IIS (run ServiceModelReg.exe /i /x and have positive result) 
Now I trying to run WCF Service consists of Service1.svc, Web.Config and bin/anyname.dll (generated by default project in VS2010) 
When I run it from the browser i catch this error:

```
    Server Error in '/ppgswcfrequests' Application.

This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.
Parameter name: item

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.
Parameter name: item
```

Maybe my virtual catalog on IIS configured wrong? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That error looks like you have more than 1 HTTP binding set up for the website, I had a similar issue about 4 weeks ago.  My solution was to get rid of any erroneous bindings I had set up in IIS for my web-site.

Comment: And what do you say about the picture? Do you have the same configuration for *.svc files? Can you explain more deeply what did you do with your IIS?

Comment: I cant read anything in your picture, I don't speak that language.  I don't have access to a box with IIS 6 on it at the moment, but I had this same error when I tried adding a 2nd HTTP binding to IIS for a website.  So check you aren't doing something like adding a binding for www.yourdomain.com and then a 2nd binding for something like yourdomain.com.  Hope this helps

Comment: Only the aspnet_isapi.dll and *.svc has meaning on this picture.

Comment: I really can't help you there as I don't have IIS 6 in-front of me.  One other thing to check is that you don't have two endpoints with the same name set up.  ie  you dont have two methods on a class with the Uri Template '/ppgswcfrequests'.